# when using soundPool my first sound loops the rest throw status 12

Tags: java, android, soundpool

when using soundPool my first sound loops the rest throw status 12
here is the code

```
public SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap;

public int playSound(int sound, int loop) {
   if (curs != sound)
   {
   curs = sound;   
       AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
       float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
       float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;  
       return soundPool.play(soundsMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, loop, 1);

     }else
   {
       return 0;
   }
 }
```

it only happens when I set loop to -1
they are very small files.

Comment: 01-24 13:11:45.383: E/AudioTrack(2073): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12  

-12 is out of memory this is not the issue the file are tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use small size files, with .ogg formate(recommanded), I also added a sleep of 1 sec to make it buffer. outofmemory basically comes if it is not buffered and tried to play

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(900);
                    mSoundManager.playSound(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.start();
```